# Готовые решения GUI - наподобие Steam/Origin

Tags: c++, mfc, steam

Подскажите где можно найти готовые решения(С исходным кодом) с модерн дизайном интерфейса, как это делают в [Steam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9GwL.png)/[Origin](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DG9wapPr_4g/maxresdefault.jpg)

Переписывать `WM_PAINT`, И `Eraise_bkgrnd` не состовляет труда, но вот делать с нуля события кнопок - отнимает у меня уйму времени.
Может быть есть уже какие то схожие решение за 2014-2016 год, и где их можно найти ?

Из тех что мне попадались давольно старенькие примитивные/решение, не слишком годяться , к примеру округленные [кнопки](http://ishodniki.ru/list/cpp/cpp_controls/1078.html)  !

----- **Update**
(немного дополню)
Меня очень заинтересовал набор инструментов для создания граф интерфейсов - CodeJoke,в него входит не мало примеров готовых sln(проектов), которые легко можно грузить в студию. Сами решения имеют прямой доступ к Нативу, к примеру `CXTPListCtrl` лишь дополняет нативный `ListCtrl`, в нем переписывается WM_PAINT, и другие события для отрисовки и прочего. Одна лишь проблема - приложение платное, и то что слито - версии 15.4 довольно старое, в новых код более лаконичный и понятный.Есть ли подобные решения за 2014-2016 год, с таким же объемом примеров ?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону Qt и QML.

Comment: @maestro - как то сложно выглядит, там все идет через их QT, любое действие. Я думал что то наподобии CJ60(MFC Ext lib) от codejockeys.com ! Я это кстати сейчас и использую, но оно уже довольно старое, может есть что то по новее ?

Comment: Лучше Qt пока не видел, это имхо. А, навскидку:  wxWidgets http://www.wxwidgets.org, Juce https://www.juce.com, Cegui http://cegui.org.uk.

Comment: @Majestio что то я сглупил - есть же  "Toolkit Pro" от тех же codejocke, правда в свободном доступе нашел только за 2011 год !

Comment: @LighFusion, наверняка в сети еще можно найти достойных/новых ... Но обычно на какой-то стадии проектирования возникает вопрос "нужен красивый интерфейс и/или нативный". Вот в этом многие либы/тулкиты разняться. Думаю, имеет смысл более четко определить цели использования. К примеру, для кастомного графического интерфейса игр - поддержка нативного интерфейса не столь важна, вернее практически не важна. Если же речь идет о программах общего назначения - найдется часть пользователей, которые будут невыносимо страдать, если нативных тем в оформлении программы не предусмотрено.

Comment: @Majestio такс ну решение я вроде нашел ! http://i.imgur.com/IVita39.png?1 , CodeJock(Toolkit Pro) идеально подходит, кастомизация там просто безгранична, огромный выбор всяких кастомных функций - которые нормально привязаны к нативу. Единственная проблема найти актуальную бесплатную версию, ибо я не компания и столько $ просто нету =)

Comment: @LighFusion, имхо, не лучший выбор. Закрытая, платная, более того, желательно халявная тулза - источник бед и несчастий :) Уверяю, на собственном опыте, 2-3 недели "общения" с Qt - и все вопросы станут несущественными. Просто взять и начать.

Comment: @Majestio вот проблема в том что нету у меня двух трех недель! и уже как то привык к этой среде CodeJock, просто сэмплов не было, а щас нашел - там в Триальной версии очень много схожих рещений! надеюсь получиться в качестве теста адаптировать сэмлы от 1.7 на 1.5.2, вот 1.6 не могу найти =)

Comment: @LighFusion, боюсь огорчить, но "сделайте мне хорошо, только не через двенедели, а прямо сейчас и бесплатно" - бывает крайне редко, очень крайне, и очень редко. Разве только в повестях Кира Булычева. Готовьтесь искать компромисс между временем и деньгами.

Comment: Автор, эту видел? Как мне думается - то что надо...
https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: Интересная штука. А C++ враппер есть к ней?

Comment: @tomato очень классно выглядит, еще бы найти готовые примеры! но в целом очень неплохо. Только 1 момент, те элементы что там доступны, можно редактировать произвольно или они как то завязаны ?

Comment: @tomato и еще 1 момент это чистый C ? т.е не каких внешних модулей(держать рядом с софтом) для прорисовки не потребуется ?